# Rails 4 conditional render cause N+1 query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a grid of posts where a user can like or unlike causing N+1 queries.

I'm rendering a collections of post which partial's has:

```
<%= post.title %>
<% if current_user.liking?(post) %>
  <%= render partial: 'posts/unlike' %>
<% else %>
  <%= render partial: 'posts/like' %>
<% end %>
...
```

User Controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @feed = @user.posts.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

This is causing one query for each post. I though using .include(:likes) but I don't know how to do it for 'current_user'

**Edit:**

I ended up creating a second query for likes thats belong to current_user

```
@liking_items = @feed.includes(:likes).where(likes: { user_id: current_user })
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the `current_user`, you can just add a where:

`@user.post.includes(:likes).where(likes: { user_id: current_user })`

(I'm assuming that the "like owner" is `user_id`).

Comment: @user is the one  who posted and current_user is the loggedin user who can like or unlike a post. How could you pass this to my view?

Comment: you just have to filter the posts and then pass it to the view, like you're doing.

Comment: I guess you query is wrong because it get post that has user_id: current_user and that's not the use case. I need Likes that has user_id: current_user